# Typescript - tsc compiler breaks my code

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I wrote this code in Typescript

```
import redis from 'redis';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL = 7200; // 2 hours

export default class Redis {

    readonly client : any;
    ttl : number = DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL;

    constructor(uri? : string, ttl : number = DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL) {
        this.client = redis.createClient(uri);
    }

    ...
}

export { Redis };
```

the compiler gives me this

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var redis_1 = require("redis");
var bluebird_1 = require("bluebird");
var DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL = 7200; // 2 hours
var Redis = (function () {
    function Redis(uri, ttl) {
        if (ttl === void 0) { ttl = DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL; }
        this.ttl = DEFAULT_REDIS_TTL;
        this.client = redis_1.default.createClient(uri);
        this.client.on('error', function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
...
exports.Redis = Redis;
exports.default = Redis
```

I don't know why 'redis.createClient(uri);`just become`redis_1.default.createClient(uri);`

I get the following error when trying to run my code in node

```
build/Lib/Cache/Redis.js:11
        this.client = redis_1.default.createClient(uri);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClient' of undefined
```

my `tsconfig` looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "mymodule",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
         "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build"
    },

    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I run the compiler in main directory

```
tsc
```

I'm using `node 6.7.2`

Comment: Please note how `export default class Redis` in your code becomes a `exports.default = Redis` in output. The same is happening with `redis`, its' being imported as `exports.default = redis`, this is why it is being used `redis_1.default.createClient`. `redis_1` is reference to `exports`, and `redis_1.default` is ref to `exports.default`. The problem you might experience is just a missing module (have you run `npm i redis`?). Try `console.log(redis)` in your code

Comment: Using different import syntax could help: `import * as redis from 'redis';` and `import * as Promise from 'bluebird';`

Comment: I run `console.log(redis)` and `console.log(redis.createClient)` and I got the redis object and output like `[Function]` for the second consolelog

Comment: i will try changing import syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your import to:

```
import * as redis from 'redis';
```

I don't think the typings for [redis](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redis/index.d.ts) has a default export. Make sure you have the latest typings.
If you have the latest typings, `import redis from 'redis';` should throw a compile time error.

Comment: +1 as [link](https://github.com/types/npm-redis/blob/master/index.d.ts) suggests the same.
`import { createClient } from 'redis';` might also be an option, if you just want to use one method

Comment: thank you this worked ... it depends on the modules, i hadnt issue with `mongodb-driver` and `express`